# Need proper bankroll management for daily withdrawals

Tags: poker-strategy, bankroll-management

A cash game player (6 card omaha) has 150-200k Rs for an investment. He plays only 6 card plo in spartan poker (Indian website)

Daily target - average 2k-4k per day
Monthly Target -> 60k-100k per Month average

All tables are RIT (run it twice)

Please advice strategy on how to reach above daily/monthly target.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just edited please check

Comment: 150-200k Rs for an investment.  Whats an "R"

Comment: Rs - Rupees (Indian currency)

Comment: What's the limits?

Comment: 10/25 (buy in range 500-2500) , 25/50 (1500-6000)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense if you don't specify a winrate

Comment: want to grind 3-4 hours daily. daily average win rate should be 100 BB/day. That's 25BB per hour of play, please suggest a strategy.

Comment: @Jon The units aren't really relelvant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There unfortunately is no silver bullet type of answer for your question, but there is some things that you can do to help you achieve your goal.

1. Most importantly, study and get really good at 6-card PLO, this will take time. away from the table study and at the table practice. Get some type of software to track your progress, review hands, and keep information on other players.
2. Play more than 3-4 hours and as many tables as you can if possible. Work towards increasing the number of tables you can play without effecting the quality of your decisions. This will help reduce your variance and amplify your rate of return (hopefully positive).
3. Don't expect consistent and stable income especially if you are a beginner, you will experience downswings and bad beats regularly. Lowering your variance by increasing volume will help mitigate this.

Assuming you are starting from 0, get a few hundred or a thousand hands in to get a baseline of your current winrate and your statistics of play. Identify leaks, issues with your mental game (tilt, confidence, etc.), evaluate your skill with multitabling, etc. Study and work to improve on these issues both away from and at the table, once they are fixed then rinse and repeat.